# dompdf error - path issue

Tags: php, dompdf

I am using the DOMPDF library to export a web page to a pdf file. Everything works just fine on my pc (localhost) but on Altervista it doesn't seem to work.
I get the following error message:

```
Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required '.../dompdf/lib/html5lib/Parser.php' (include_path='.:') in .../dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php on line 320
```

It's likely to be a path issue. Or maybe some kind of configuration is required in dompdf.
Can anyone help? Thanks!
alessandro

Comment: On Windows, capitalization does not matter, but on Linux is does. Is the name of the file really capitalized?

Comment: Also, the three dots at the start shouldn't work on Linux (unless you've set that as an alias)

Comment: the name of the file is capitalized.

Comment: I used the dots to avoid copying the entire path, which is actually correct.

Comment: You don't technically need the HTML5 parser, but it helps dompdf deal with poorly formed HTML. You might try disabling the parser. The path seems correct, did you confirm the files copied and are accessible to your server user?